# Compare string with ASP.net Membership Answer in the form of Hashing and saltvalue

Tags: asp.net

I need to compare the answer in with the aspnet_membership tables PasswordAnswer value.

The text in Password answer is in the form of Hashed. What algorithm they have used how they implemented the Salt value in ASP.net Membership Provider.

I have tried hashing (sh1) and compared with text what is salt value

How to hash my answer value.

string answer = "one";
string hashedvalue = "dfdsfsdfdsfdsfdfdf";

I need to compare this both.

I have converted the answer to hashed format. But both are different> I think due to salt value. How can I utilize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [Membership class' ValidateUser method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx) to do this.